# Nifty tools to visualisation in Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I would like to write e-learning application responsible for **visualisation of sorting algorithms** and test effectiveness. I will use Python and PySide(PyQt) but it would be great to use any nifty utils to make this simply visualisation. 
**The purpose of this visualisation is to show steps of working sorting algorithms.**

Do you know any nifty utils to make simple visualisation, animations in Python ?
Maybe PySide has something to do visualisation?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) and its animation features:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

random_list = [10,3,5,4,9,1,6,7,2,8]

def bubble_sort():
    data = random_list
    for i in range(len(data)-1):
        for j in range(i, len(data)-1):
            a, b = data[j], data[j+1]
            if a > b:
                data[j], data[j+1] = b, a
                yield data

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
def update(data):
    ax.clear()
    ax.hlines(range(len(data)), 0, data, 'red')
    ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 9.5)
update(random_list)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, bubble_sort, interval=250)
plt.show()
```

You'd just need to change `bubble_sort()` to implement other algorithms and yield a list of numbers to plot at each iteration.

matplotlib can also be [embedded in PySide](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/PySide), but I didn't test it.

Comment: I tried to install matplotlib (with easy_install) - http://screenshooter.net/4248873/skljtgp #1, http://screenshooter.net/4248873/glygfam #2 
but installation exited with error, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

PySide is just a thin wrapper around Qt, and Qt doesn't have any built-in support for visualization of algorithms. It's designed for building traditional [WIMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WIMP_%28computing%29) GUIs—that is, windows full of widgets like text boxes or sliders.

You can animate Qt by representing each of your visualized objects as a widget and manually moving the widgets around, or you can just create blank canvases and draw your animations on top, but either way, Qt isn't really helping you that much.

A game-oriented library like PyGame might be more appropriate—you can represent each object as a sprite, and use the sprite animation facilities.

Or you could look for a visualization library instead of a general-purpose GUI library.

Comment: Though Qt does have animation facilities.

Answer (score 1):

Qt allows you to create UI in two different ways:

1. Widget-based, this allow you to create conventional applications with static UI (QPushButton, QTextEdit, ...). Doing animation with these UI components might be cumbersome
2. Declarative UI, we use QML (Qt Meta Language) to create dynamic UI (UI with lots of animations/transitions). Take a look at [QML Examples](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdeclarativeexamples.html)

QML allows you to quickly create the UI, and easily animate it. You can use QDeclarativeView in PySide to load and display QML in your application.

You can expose data (list of numbers) from Python to QML via QObject's signal-slot mechanism or properties. Lots of examples can be found in [this repository](http://gitorious.org/pyside-qml-examples).